# Bootstrap 4 não coloca colunas lado a lado no Angular8

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-8

Boa tarde pessoal.
Eu não sei o que está acontecendo com o Bootstrap em um projeto que estou fazendo que ele não coloca as colunas lado a lado. Já tentei alterar o tamanho, já tentei tirar as rows e não funciona. Essas cols são geradas dentro de um ngFor, e mesmo que eu tire fora, elas não ficam lado a lado de maneira nenhuma. Alguem tem alguma ideia do que está acontecendo?

container.component.html

```
<div class="container">
<app-logo></app-logo>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

catalogo.component.html

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let item of produto">
<div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xl-6">
    <p>{{item.name}}</p>
    <!-- <p>{{item.images[0].url}}</p> -->
</div>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu loop está criando novas linhas por isso não está alinhando lado a lado. Você deve fazer o loop na div com as classes de colunas. Segue a alteração:

```
<div class="row">
  <div *ngFor="let item of produto"
        class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xl-6">
    <p>{{item.name}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Puts era isso mesmo cara. Eu tinha feito isso, so que eu tava colocando o loop depois das classes. Valeu cara, valeu mesmo

Comment: Por nada. Sucesso ;)